# How to add circle with number on ion card header

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I was trying to make some card with numbering(circle with number inside), but something seems wrong.
I can't make it circle and center

[Here's what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrF2M.png) but when I try to make it, it become like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk6aF.png)

Here is some of my code,

```
<ion-card-header style="padding:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #9c9c9c;">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col class="numberCircle">1</ion-col>
    <ion-col>John Doe</ion-col>
    <ion-col>Posting</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-card-header>
```

css

```
.numberCircle {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        padding: 4px;
    
        background: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #666;
        color: #666;
        text-align: center;
    
        font: 12px Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

Comment: @lussac it didn't work, still the same

Comment: @lussac your ion-card-header doesn't use flex so it wont have the same output as the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier when you put the number in another element and center that

```css
ion-row.row {
    padding: 5px 26px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

ion-row.row ion-col {
   flex-grow: 0;
}

.numberCircle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-flex;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    flex-grow: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.numberCircle span {
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    font: 12px Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<ion-card-header style="padding:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #9c9c9c;">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col class="numberCircle">
      <span>
          1
      </span>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>John Doe</ion-col>
    <ion-col>Posting</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-card-header>
```

Comment: I've tried it but it's still the same result. the circle is still stretching

Comment: Did you add the diaplay:inline-flex; to .numberCircle?

Comment: hmm do you have your full code online somewhere so i can check it there?

Comment: here's some [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tjlr1i)

Comment: I've updated my answer to be compatible with your demo

Comment: it is true that it becomes a circle, but everything becomes shifted to the left and does not match the column. As you can see, I divided it into 3 columns and want to make it in the middle of the column

Comment: Well the best way to do this is to edit the html so that the number col is in between the 2 others. you are using flex so you could also add order to them so give the ion-col John Doe order:1; and the ion-col with the number order: 2; in css

Comment: sorry sir, but I think you missunderstand what I mean, maybe you can look on **Here's what I want** image. sorry for my bad english anyway

Comment: Could you update your demo with the new code so I can see how it looks now?

Comment: already updated with your css
you can check again [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tjlr1i)

Comment: I've updated the code again, I think this wil give you the desired result

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)

Comment: I fixed it by adding some padding to the .numberCircle class